# Using apply family functions when loop over arguments in a function in r

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, apply, mapply

How can I loop over arguments in a functions using one of the apply type function to make code faster in R? For example, I have created a function to compute the joint mutual information of three random variables

```
### Function to loop over: Joint Mutual Information I({x_1,x_2};y)
library(infotheo)
JMI <-function(x1,x2,y){
      entropy(cbind(x1,x2),method="emp") + entropy(y, method="emp") - 
      entropy(cbind(x1,x2,y),method="emp")
   }
```

Suppose I have two matricies (x1, x2)  and one vector y like:

```
#### randomly generate binary variables from a bernoulli distribution
set.seed(12345)
f1 <- rbinom(n=300,size=1,prob=0.5)
f2 <- rbinom(n=300,size=1,prob=0.5)
f3 <- rbinom(n=300,size=1,prob=0.5)

## creat y using xor operation of the two feature: x1 XOR x2
#  this mean that y is 1 if f1[i]!=f2[i] and 0 otherwise
y <- ifelse(f1==f2,0,1)
x1 <-cbind(f1,f2)
x2 <- cbind(x1,f3)
```

Now, I want to loop over x1 and x2 in the JMI function. Using for-loops this looks like this:

```
# a length(x1) x length(x2)-Matrix with zeros
jmi <- matrix(rep(0,ncol(x2)*ncol(x1)),
          nrow=ncol(x1),ncol=ncol(x2))
#### For loops to be avoided
for(i in 1:ncol(x1)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(x2)){
    jmi[i,j] <- JMI(x1[,i],x2[,j],y)
  }#end out for(j)
}#end inner for(i)
```

Is there an easy way to avoid both for-loops?

Comment: I think you mixed up rows and columns in your last code section. When you define `jmi`, you use `nrow = ncol(x2)`, but in the loop, the row index `i` runs over `1:ncol(x1)`.

Comment: The edit is not enough. Now the problem occurs in the call for `JMI`: i runs over the columns of `x2` but is used to get the columns of `x1` (and vice versa). Please run your code before you post it. I'll update my solution once you posted a working example.

Comment: I m sorry but the code runs just fine on my computer. i runs over the columns of x1 and is used in x1 and the same for x2

Comment: After your last edit, it does indeed run fine. Thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 1):

This  is a solution using apply:

```
g <- expand.grid(1:ncol(x1), 1:ncol(x2))
v <- apply(g, 1, function(i) JMI(x1[, i[1]], x2[, i[2]], y))
jmi <- matrix(v, nrow = ncol(x1))
jmi
##             [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
## [1,] 0.003809514 0.693147181 0.01082319
## [2,] 0.693147181 0.006485284 0.01152807
```

It proceeds in three steps:

- The indices for the columns of the matrices `x1` and `x2` are created using `expand.grid`. This creates a data frame `g` with two columns that contain all combinations of `i` and `j` that your for loop goes through.
- Then `apply` is used to go through all the rows of `g` and apply `JMI` to the corresponding columns of `x1` and `x2`. This results in a vector `v`.
- Finaly, `v` is converted to a matrix.

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped. Could you please update your question such that your example code is actually running through? I will then make sure that the question matches the updated answer.

Comment: Yeah it works but unfortunately it seems to be not faster than the two for-loops.

Comment: There is no reason to expect that it should be faster.

Comment: Well, but the only reason why I try to avoid the for-loops is because there are slow. If the apply() solution here is not much faster than what is the point in using it?

Comment: Using the apply family is mostly about readability, not speed. In the end, the bottleneck are the R functions that you are calling, not the loop. I measured your three calls of `entropy()` and found that they take about 270, 265, 330 microseconds, respectively. When calculating the matrix, you call each of them six times, taking an estimated 5190 microseconds. When I measure the time your for loops take, I get 5230 microseconds. All the time is spend evaluating `entropy()`, so this function is to blame for the slowness of your code.